# Why can't I import web3 when running py script on Atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor, web3py

I am working my way through the quckstart for web3py here.  I'm able to use python3 and work through the first couple lines:

```
>>>from web3 import Web3
>>> w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<infura-project-id>'))
>>> from web3.auto.infura import w3
>>> w3.eth.block_number
12750187
```

I'm using Atom and I have the following packages installed:

```
atom-python-run
script
```

I've also added `python3` to the F5 and F6 Commands
[image]

I've written the following script to begin playing around with the code as I'm trying to learn how to use web3py to interact with Ethereum:

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/,0000000'))
```

When I run that snippet, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookdbw/Dropbox/Personal/Python_Blockchain_Project/w3_Script_Testing.py", line 3, in <module>
from web3 import Web3
ImportError: No module named web3
```

Why can't the script import Web3?

**EDIT**
Per comments, I followed the instructions [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).  Here's what my console now says:

```
macbookdbw@Davids-MacBook-Pro Python_Blockchain_Project % source env/bin/activate
(env) macbookdbw@Davids-MacBook-Pro Python_Blockchain_Project % 
which python
```

`/Users/macbookdbw/Dropbox/Personal/Python_Blockchain_Project/env/bin/python`

`(env) macbookdbw@Davids-MacBook-Pro Python_Blockchain_Project %`

Same error.

Comment: Does it work if you run `python3 w3_Script_Testing.py` from the command line?

Comment: yes.  I added `print(w3)` and got this in console: `<web3.main.Web3 object at 0x7f9b99932ee0>`

Comment: Hmm. Try pip installing it again for kicks.

Comment: Installing web3?

Comment: Yes, web3. Also check your venv?

Comment: @Ezra what is venv?  Virtual environment?  If so, do you have a resource I can read?  I can’t figure out what all that means.

Comment: Venv is a tool for isolating package installations between projects. My theory is that atom is using a different venv (virtual environment) than the command line. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Thanks.  Gave it a shot.  No luck.

Answer (score 1):

found this [here](https://newbedev.com/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts).

Added this to the script:

```
import sys
print("Version ",sys.version)
import web3

from web3 import Web3
w3 =Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/0000000'))
print(w3)
```

Can't say I know why, but it works.